# mixing process substitution and pipes in zsh

Tags: linux, pipe, zsh, process-substitution

Using ZSH, I am trying to wrap a sed command into a function, then use it, while mixing pipes with process substution.
Let me explain with an example:

```
$ echo "test text" | gzip > myfile.gz
$ sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' <(zcat myfile.gz) | more
test text
$ ncat() { sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' $@; }
$ zcat myfile.gz | ncat | more
test text
$ ncat <(zcat myfile.gz) | more
sed: can't read /proc/self/fd/13: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, in those 2 out of those 3 usages work. The last one is the one that intrigues me here. (Note that all commands work with bash)

Can you explain why the output of a function that uses process substitution in input, is not usable through a pipe?

I am not looking for a workaround to just make my example work. I am looking for an explanation, because I couldn't find one.

FYI `sed` is not relevant here, I tried with multiple other commands (echo, cat...), and got the same outcome

Comment: Where is the named pipe?

Comment: Are you talking about process substitution with `<(...)`?

Comment: yes <(zcat myfile.gz)

Comment: you can mix process substitution and pipes, since it works in the second command. I think the issue is that you're trying to use the process substitution as an argument to a function.

Comment: The function is being run in a subshell because of the pipe, and that subshell doesn't inherit the FD connected to the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pipe the `ncat` function's output, it has to be run in a subshell. For some reason, the FD connected to the process substitution pipe is not being inherited by this subshell. Since it uses `/proc/self/fd`, if the FD isn't open in the child process, the attempt to read from it fails.

It seems like a bug to me, since a function should work similarly to external functions in this regard.

This isn't Linux-specific, I reproduced the problem on MacOS running zsh 5.3.

It only seems to happen when the subshell is created for a pipe. To see when a subprocess is created and whether the FD is inherited, I changed the function to:

```
ncat() { echo $$;sh -c 'echo $PPID';echo "$@";ls /dev/fd; }
```

(`/dev/fd` is the Mac equivalent of `/proc/self/fd`.)

If I run

```
(ncat <(gzcat myfile.gz ))
```

The parentheses create a subshell, but the FD associated with the process substitution *is* shown in the `ls /dev/fd` output.